# Protect file for download

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security

I have a page which includes a video player (Flash or Silverlight). How I can protect the video file from being directly downloaded?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I prevent/make it hard to download my flash video?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142157/how-can-i-prevent-make-it-hard-to-download-my-flash-video)

Answer (score 1):

[Silverlight DRM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838192%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Well, I would suggest working with some kind of an authentication key.

When you print out the URL to the flash file on your html page, calculate some authentication key, maybe based on the name, and/or creation date of the flash file, and perhaps the sessionid or userid of the current user.

You'll end up with http://blabla.com/media/myflash.swf?auth=XXXX&userid=234

Let MVC catch the request (so turn RouteExistingFiles off in your global.asax). And check if the authentication key is correct.