# Drupal: Which video module to use with an Amazon S3 "already uploaded" file that should be available only to registered users?

Tags: drupal, video, video-streaming

I need to play some videos in my Drupal site, and need to choose a module that can actually do that. I´ve checked out some video modules, but they are primarily to upload videos, but I don´t need to upload a video, I just need to use an already uploaded one. And I need that only registered users to be able to access them.

This is my use case:

- I have an Amazon S3 account. I´ve already uploaded some videos in there.
- I want users to access those videos from my drupal site.
- I´m the only person that will be uploading videos.
- I want only registered users to access those videos.
- **I want the link to the Amazon S3 file to be hidden, so people won´t be able to share in other places the videos (no hot links, etc).** (Yeah, I know [there´s no way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142157/how-can-i-prevent-make-it-hard-to-download-my-flash-video) to stop people from sharing the video, but maybe make it a little more difficult to do it?)

Thanks for your insight!
Rosamunda

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would simply make a CCK ([Project Page](http://drupal.org/project/cck)) textfield and add it to your content type. In that field you enter the Amazon S3 url.

Then I would suggest using a flash video player with a HTML5 backup, [JWPlayer](http://www.longtailvideo.com/) does exactly that.

Last step would be to modify the node-{content-type}.tpl.php file to print the CCK field so the player can pick it up (I won't go into specifics on how to embed the player, I leave that up to JWPlayer website).

As with the restriction to only registered users you can manage the permissions in admin/user/permissions .

Comment: In fact, that´s a brilliant idea! THANKS!